# Is there a jquery work that can make css shadow-roundedcorners works on IE6 and Up

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, css

I need to make a cross browser `css`, to keep my websites look same in each browser.

Is there any Cross Browser `CSS` sheet, which can be also called as "`css` hack" to make  **shadows** and **rounded corners** shown as same in all browsers and is it posible to use these two at the same time in `IE6 or higher`.

Ive found some `css` sheets that does these seperately but not together.
so if there is a way to make these two different css ability work together in `IE6 or higher`, i would like to know.

Comment: also im sorry about my bad usage of english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using CSS3PIE available here: http://css3pie.com/about/

From the site:

> PIE stands for Progressive Internet Explorer. It is an IE attached behavior which, when applied to an element, allows IE to recognize and display a number of CSS3 properties. Consider, if you will, the following CSS:

```
#myElement {
  background: #EEE;
  padding: 2em;
  -moz-border-radius: 1em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
```

> This results in a box with nicely rounded corners in any of today's modern browsers, except of course for IE 6, 7, or 8, which all display a square box. However, add the following single rule to that CSS:

```
#myElement {
  ...
  behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

> Now the exact same rounded corners appear in IE! That's all there is to it. No, really, I mean it.

Slightly slows load time, but works great. Also allows things like drop shadows and gradients.

Comment: ty for additional info about its usage. i loved it.

Answer (score 2):

[CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com) is what you need. Make sure you read the documentation first, though it's very easy to get working.

Comment: ty for help this is a real powerfull tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter for shadow in ie

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#000000', Direction=135, Strength=10);  /* IE */
```

also u can use this JS for curve
http://blue-anvil.com/jquerycurvycorners/test.html#fragment-2

Comment: yes thats good but need to apply in CSS styles z-index and position: relative  

Check this Issue http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#z-index

Comment: well in my css sheet everything has a z-index + relative position but thanks i got ur point so good job.